# How to connect spring cloud config server to Bitbucket using SSH keys?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to create a spring cloud config server to connect to git repository(bitbucket) using an SSH URI. I am following Spring Cloud Config.

I generated key pair using the command

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096 -C "sweta"
```

pasted the .pub file content in the ssh section of my bitbucket account but when I am running the server that is a spring boot application, I am getting an invalid privateKey exception.

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=git@webprod:7999/service-micro/service-properties.git
spring.cloud.config.server.git.ignoreLocalSshSettings=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n\
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEA49ZAmVWvAMKqOqGwQq8vhaXsA3LiYWbk1G9CTAjLW6i+NXHR\
Fjk2qdUTRGsAZUCIIbgSK5hW1Ciaj8PU+Cuqz5oVaAzvNxQy+zvj4emi0KLJDhYk\
KaeeOpz1R4fT6QoIP7cwugdI3e7GRqLFSZ2MQovHJKfTLjWhLgZj2YzS6Jvdl1DS\
S6K9p2stf7daXi9A8Ysp0/8ccQSeZm1pdV2ppms0uHwkAq9pd2WkofSZP7Nrfhno\
gIqgkvWBuHSmSZKFFPXG826QyDtbmfUfQsH0Mm8TlK8tVy6NTE5/q1NzjepbK4mX\
eFnWITM6rViqQ6lAOzPTqd45qWez60yypYGs4jZjHQwioeAHqQCI1O7KstOPoMEn\
Ujr72u9FbKptKF/3JeqhchocajBnvSnvJawip50E1uZAh7YDx+g+U4s7W2w3ka2w\
oAtRke7JjDq/Lej4CmzMliNsD/4fxC3+RgB9wAcCYO9BvE/aM3mx/0O2KWTzEkAN\
JnP6jn1PbrKFExwL7bVjWwIxDvU4zz6bKN1MOh5GT+6e/eNVANAG6o8pZz9tcTFu\
JX1qBFvZJznoe4/kpIvbiLUEOL6IIotf1P5UXVw1jwEzEnQ30R3ZC2XUiYusQgz+\
w1gMFYbKo6IpNzFnSdRmcDQ26Tg1tvtEfvERMadKVWr14Vtvf8RD/K60TsMCAwEA\
AQKCAgBW149/4pz12T0xY/ffMw8WDgxLtDp9jc6i+lV2zdNVeJgnnt5nbh9b1I+n\
gHGCJnq8/4BNhZ9y9pcTPT2r6lkNEFogcu2rPNPB1y4hKgCZLbMc32uhRPaWuMT1\
Ityu8tf6EUVNYwFvNlf1DI3OZXLU2pppal6gOmjZNi5Q+dBaQS7RQkkl8z3+1mdd\
SvHy/GfwqW6kE5UvrucBe6q6xZyohixuNUM0ks/MZr29zZGsKiNKyW1JsY1K9rEf\
MbdAS8zWFGhk2TvuVlGv+TKVK4B8yMHZ5nuNw3ywHSukjgZ5jV561dMaWIO52+D9\
udIMQDLvXe3LzZyE6bY2deGSHD9csd53mqSYxjV8bVHIXckIODgpw3b0Z6vj/0ut\
OOj02bGy8DjWpVnidxz9oXdHEMFDS9lfTQnUnT7mdm+bAlZjMQHNtVF5DVWUakAI\
KQ2jrVIj1v4oi5bd4k9TFYzn0RiWQuQGIwXQf09jh0/1jUCiX0yYoOUyJnVUfZKW\
dzX/My0nJlclwvZqwmRaIrfe8S7VmZ5jhDxvg2frzN8fCf9S88nbOcevr0fKq1OS\
B2MgNKoBQnPRxr3KVBOlIpXaqnbkQYHU21GVIkWqLAenstCl9yc1ecRyHHAcXR5R\
phmPorKUwzlw08bX+yqlqs6Ppm/FNwndTR6KQl4tMdzNVPFuIQKCAQEA9wQiu6rF\
cg21MlKTvxQThw9JqL7ZPZ8Cm0e3bybXc7vhZYeYnYI9xKAlFLpu4PTB65z3iWyK\
vB9KU6KJqB2C2oEKKItbC4xzsGSSgT05lMGwHYLuCm0Yo9zg1s+doEo2A7NLP9rT\
jF8lQnKy0stUs+0HLoo7I7P1j12peyuDnfx5orvl8ce+ByYMYO1Echq4c6aEQgEW\
Xc3CQKNv6lY3iX92HyYf+uz8saKgLd55Qy2wNaonAW3YM3i7Yw0PUvIotcTlW0kJ\
DQvrhcKrM0udF3wFB2mnummXiv6+FOKtlm7k1/n90FMz3A4zPqDxPDhErt6gc+/E\
35ASeeCcLOUTrQKCAQEA7B+L/cifcc55Fdg9qll3UWqifCLeQYfZkPNfWHruzMOP\
7U6T8MU3xArwBzfS9JQh+2QRotUJfQiRM82pe6LvFJfBx6TwEwJ3Z6DsWZDox5ai\
CRZrnYgc7lCbOarkkt1BgIS71rbunTHQNP92xjNu0zjgArw8pZZMUz8/EcE04uYm\
WxCaThAOoubPv0h1hb0O9sn3LoYCFigbtUboc7t7mPB9zRi95+jxqSpMO6kwLDnI\
ojk1fCtqfD3V2y9sbMWLWIhKkvNWY5OQJdJfGzTW5MiaJb36m4V2BLSVnJLuKHRn\
ON2LoRhYfZ5YGwr+giUtA2qOPLaXc/TpYBgKXQK6LwKCAQBPIuANx5QiCgo26QW0\
fbYT2u36RcpLV5n6LWuzDHqR9Wssn9hg/czUJYo7rc6/+yn1VgBn4oI/6rZhPP1l\
Aq9dWWHrw1mTxZd6t33IMdk0syi9C6k/ZdwzAxx1NWaGZ8AOR26gMnb7za+eLijk\
J4gnbJSUcGyp74mIOLWHZFVyU+SUIiZ0400Z9TKaCumWtMDLLFnK25ZSzwygsLu2\
E5EPV+p76DbuqOX78uHmUBQBVa3SQ4TjjFFrjA5cmV6DcFligoYITMm9iEgYPlmi\
wWK+l1j1GwBFVHbcbOhwwH5kZ3qhRtHt3/oJUfNQ6Tbf2BcI/wHgorwr83g326Gt\
MGaxAoIBAQDjtPSK9EuXM9efkl69hfPEJ0K01ediaMEOwTTEniDmhP2qi2mt+nLx\
8t5RB6u/w48V4QYE8s9orbdhrsbv/Uv0nvj4L/55Rpqh7BWhtlZWC9UNUHrNe3Ly\
+/cF4OD3JLpDVz3SLa3lGCHCyk3fi8AnoCSfXqpZwZyvd0G6PIlk+zAoB9XWzDNh\
M5dKz3TOWWkx48klK4Sdm2ZFJjGLUlU6Q0n+XQret809JxZHPry/GaZ7kxIaQcA6\
OmOfMZetOcBMy3qnRlWcR7TuVHb1RLqr/Sxyk0g3bLhIh2H0kdlsV/0nYLeDzneg\
BPDQe4S/O1yye7LZp/hckeXxjp2H3tZvAoIBAQCDZymWIl26Fr9EF/InFYv45A/G\
q+BX8E+1W7cvpRoV1l9gHRY1meE2aBEjIZ2jO61gz5bflYjlTU7G9ERGU/73HUFG\
1sNemQuEt601KejgfR4JZNTsb4Pqe5gmhxdPEtG5kAlsPY8k8nLbs6URU5aH0Cuq\
fBVXXGELvGka82XYtIC0c1Kj+4e2j4vL/w3zZ/cyPgmeaR8e6bM31L1AGccWEaEi\
/x8ybvCwQqcbP49bDlv5rmPMAUO34bRjMxK3XJZbbjJrhNdb8a89zGsx4+s8k+ZH\
/gFdvOAB6A5xw1YuMsryQCYPJOrEZips1apEEZ0yqSUcdve7OanfpXiiEiCs\n\
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I also added \n and \ in the end. However, still no luck.

Below is the error log:

```
Description:

Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.config.server.git' to org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentProperties failed:
    Reason: Property 'spring.cloud.config.server.git.privateKey' must be set when 'spring.cloud.config.server.git.ignoreLocalSshSettings' is specified
```

Can someone guide me What am I missing?

Comment: The error message says property `spring.cloud.config.server.git.privateKey` must have the private key, but you set the private key in a different property `spring.cloud.config.server.git.password`.

Comment: @ChinHuang Thank you very much for your reply. I made the change. However, I'm getting the below error: ``` Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: git@webprod:7999/service-micro/service-properties.git: Cannot login at webprod.test.com:22
 at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.sshd.SshdSession.connect(SshdSession.java:174) ~[org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache-5.13.1.2022061
  Caused by: org.apache.sshd.common.SshException: No more authentication methods available
 at org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientUserAuthService.tryNext(ClientUserAuthService.java:353) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0] ```

Comment: @ChinHuang Do I need to add anything in the known_hosts file?